# Issue with submitting jobs with batchtools on cluster

Tags: r, cluster-computing

**Script**

```
ids <- findJobs()

ids[, chunk := 1]

batchtools::submitJobs(
reg = reg, ids = chunk(findNotDone(ids, reg)$job.id, n.chunks = 1),
resources = list(ncpus = 1, memory = 8GB,
                  walltime = 70, partition = "fast"))
```

**Error**

> Error in convertIds(reg, ids, default = .findNotSubmitted(reg = reg),  : 
>     Duplicated ids provided